# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import; After updating from Angular 2 RC5 to Angular 2 Final;

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I have ust updated my app from Angular 2 RC5 to Angular 2 final. After that i am getting error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import;**

I have all packages of latest version even updated the node to 6.7.0. I am using:

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
Angular 2 Final
Angular 2 Material
WebPack

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App development",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "npm install",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.2",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/menu": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.20.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^3.10.3",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://optimint.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/HRP"
  },
  "author": "Deepak Dalal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "-vs-binding": {
    "AfterBuild": [],
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "setup"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

typings

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "resolution": "app/Scripts/typings",
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "hammerjs": "registry:dt/hammerjs#2.0.8+20160724063812",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statements.They should be like this,

```
import { MdRippleModule } from '@angular2-material/core';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
```